# Isn't it time for SPONSORED questions on S/O?

Tags: feature-request

You know, give a little, get a little.

Scratch my back and I'll scratch yours!

If I have an $800 project due tomorrow and I'm stuck, out of time, just not going to make it and *you're* able to help *now*...you can pretty much name your price, mate!

Maybe there could be "pinned" questions on the top of the page that cycle through the various sponsored topics at the time.

Additional reputation for prompt answers to sponsored questions?

I suppose this is something like the bounty feature but with less bush-beating.

Many angles for disagreement however you know the scenario is commonplace and would benefit many, including this fine site if they choose to partake in the action.

How bout the cost of a decent server now adays!! Am I right??

Comment: You don't really want to sponsor questions, you want to hire someone to do your work for you.

Comment: _"If I have an $800 project due tomorrow and I'm stuck, out of time, just not going to make it and you're able to help now...you can pretty much name your price, mate!"_ You loose! Learn how to use resources right. SO isn't the right one for that kind of attitude.

Comment: If you have an $800 project due tomorrow and you're stuck, you dun goofed.

Comment: @psubsee2003, I want motivated collaboration when I know I can't do something myself.

Comment: This is not (and hopefully will never be) a hire a contractor or consultant site. It's also not (and never will be) a site to do your work, complete your project, do your homework, or solve your personal coding issues site. It's a repository of *knowledge* that will benefit lots of people, and if it just happens to solve the problem you're currently having in the process that's a great side effect, but it's not the goal or purpose of any of the [se] sites. (And if you have an $800 project due tomorrow and I can name my price, it's $8000.)

Comment: No.  It is however about time that SO users named "John Smith" ought to be forced to use their real name.  We wouldn't have to put up with this question.

Comment: @HansPassant Explain this, please. Something wrong with anonymity? You'd make a fine dictator. It's an innocent question that could've increased revenues for S/O. Why not ban all mental giants who don't take anyone not at their level seriously? Now that's a vision.

Comment: @JohnSmith Stack Overflow users are already motivated by reputation.  If you feel you aren't getting enough of a response to your questions, then you may have other issues in how you are asking questions.  Secondly, Stack Overflow is not for "collaboration".  It is a Q&A site for specific programming problems.

Comment: `"How bout the cost of a decent server now adays!! Am I right??"` -- about as wrong as I've ever seen in meta. You know how this will play out -- rich spoiled students paying folks to do their CS homework for them. Let's avoid going this route. Ever. I like the current equation: If you want prompt decent help, then your best bet is to ask a decent well-formed question. If you still need help, give it a rep bounty.

Comment: As an aside, if you're realizing that you're not going to hit your deadline the *day of*, there'd be very few developers capable of getting fully up-to-speed in that short amount of time to get you back on track.  If there were, their consultation fees would be easily twice as much as $800, though.

Comment: Agree with Makoto. Software is kinda of a big industry. It would easily cost that entire project's budget to actually hire some of the users here for a day.

Comment: Try [Fiver](https://www.fiverr.com/).

Comment: There is enough interest here, it looks to me.  I think the time is ripe, to spawn a near-clone of stackoverflow.com -- assuming the source is open -- and enable the feature of money-sponsored assistance.   The narrow minded purists can stay on the original site. The rest can use either site they choose, depending on their needs.    IS SO OPEN SOURCE?

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson No. No, it's not.

Answer (score 51):

The primary purpose of Stack Overflow is *not* to help you get your work done on time. It's to build a lasting repository of programming knowledge. There are plenty of places on the Web to hire programmers for short-term projects. Anyone interested in these types of projects are already there. It doesn't serve the primary purpose of Stack Overflow to bring that feature here.