# Can I offer money on an external site for somebody to answer my question on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, rules

I haven't yet accumulated the reputation to post a bounty to a question, but as its important to me, I'd like to offer some sort of incentive to draw in an answer for it.

I was wondering if it would be a violation of any sort for me to offer a cash price on an external site for someone to answer the question I have posted here.

I wanted to create a posting on an external site like Elance offering a small sum of cash to anyone who would be able to post an answer successfully resolving a question that I've posted and haven't received and answer to.

Comment: Try http://www.topcoder.com

Comment: Thank you. I'd appreciate it if you could post that as an answer so I could upvote and choose it as the answer. You've answered my question perfectly.

Comment: Why you need to offer money here. There are lots of freelancer site where you can post a job for answering your question.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283328/isnt-it-time-for-sponsored-questions-on-s-o

Comment: More and more often people are using the downvote as a 'dislike' button instead of a 'not useful' button...but that's none of my business.

Comment: @carla Voting is different on Meta -- votes are also used to indicate agreement or disagreement with the post.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Stack Exchange isn't able to control what you choose to do outside of SE. But it can take action on any accounts/posts that you have on SE. As well as actions on accounts of users that have posted on your questions/answers and their own posts to your posts.

So it would suck to offer money on another site to answer your question on SE, and end up having your question closed as off-topic/too broad/etc or even be deleted. If it was brought to a mod's attention that you were offering money elsewhere for whoever answers your question correctly, a mod could delete your question if they wanted and give you suspension or account termination. Will/would they do that? Who knows for sure. But there is that risk.

So if you really want to offer money for someone to help you, then hire someone on a site that allows that. Sure you can still post the same question on SE, but don't make any mention of them having to answer on SE or anything like that. SE doesn't need to be involved in this at all.